# SmartGWT *.ds.xml files can be accessed via web browser

Tags: java, maven, smartgwt

I have a Web Maven project that uses SmartGWT. After doing maven install, several *.ds.xml files are created in the **install** folder under *sc/schema* subfolder. These files are:

```
DataSource.ds.xml
DataSourceField.ds.xml
DataSourceStore.ds.xml
DBListDS.ds.xml
DBSchema.ds.xml
JVMClassTreeDS.ds.xml
QuartzJobs.ds.xml
QuartzScheduler.ds.xml
QuartzTriggers.ds.xml
SchemaSet.ds.xml
SimpleType.ds.xml
Validator.ds.xml
WebService.ds.xml
WebServiceOperation.ds.xml
WSDLMessage.ds.xml
WSOperationHeader.ds.xml
XSComplexType.ds.xml
XSElement.ds.xml
```

They can be accessed via browser at my website link my_site/*.ds.xml, which the browser display a red error message. I have searched around and found nothing related to accessibility via browser of these files.

How do I restrict access to these files? Will the pose any vulnerability issue? Is it safe to let them be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly safe to leave those files accessible.

In fact the application may need to access them from the client site to function correctly.

Comment: I dont think so, but anyway, would you please elaborate why it is safe ? or why its even needed. Something which your application using to build component should not get exposed. I mean that is not the idea. IMO

Comment: User can access those files in browser too, which I think that should not be allowed.

Comment: You may add a check on referral to make sure they are not accessed directly but in the end they don't contain any private information or pose security risk. So, whatever :)